# jQuery to call a function on mouseover of any <a> tag?

Tags: jquery

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
$(a).on('mouseover', function() {
    alert('alert');
});
```

Comment: Don't know your use case, but consider using "mouseenter" event. See https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What errors do you get? What is, or isn't, happening? Also, unless `a` is a variable, you probably meant `$('a')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('a').on('mouseover', function() {
    alert('alert');
});
```

Wrap it in `document.ready` as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('mouseover', function() {
        alert('alert');
    });
});
```

It works here. https://jsfiddle.net/3648w1gr/

Comment: This still is not working, my jQuery is definitely attached.

Comment: Try wrapping your function in `$( document ).ready` as above.

Comment: Thanks, that works, how do access a <a> wrapped in a <g>?

Comment: You could do `$("g > a")` if you have `<g><a>Test</a></g>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `$(a)` to `$('a')` and the name of the event is `mouseenter`:

```
$('a').on('mouseenter', function() {
alert('alert');
});
```